# Selecting id using jQuery on the fly

Tags: jquery, html

Using the checkbox styling system here (with a few slight modifications): http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-javascript/jquery-fancy-custom-radio-and-checkbox/ I have the following jQuery code:

```
if($(this).data("checked") == true)
{
    $("#" + this.id + "l").css("padding", "8px 0px 0px 0px");
    $(this).css({backgroundPosition:"center -"+(imgHeight*3)+"px"});
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox" id="c2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbx2" name="num[]" value="2" />
</div>
<div class="cbxLabel" id="c2l">Opt 2</div>
```

The part I'm having trouble with is the `$("#" + this.id + "l")`. No matter what I try, it doesn't select the id of the div with "Opt 2" properly. I'm trying to style that part of the div but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Looks like your code should work, as long as `this` is a reference to the `c2` element. Is this code happening in an event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $_this = $(this);
$('#'+$_this.attr('id')+'1').css("padding", "8px 0px 0px 0px");
$_this.css({backgroundPosition:"center -"+(imgHeight*3)+"px"});
```

Comment: `.attr('id')` is just a slower way of doing `this.id`.

Comment: @Baez: The only actual thing in this answer that would change the outcome of the code is the fact that the selector is using `1` instead of the `l` that your markup shows. Was that your actual HTML?

Comment: @Josh: Please don't forget to declare variables using `var` so you're not creating globals.

Comment: I changed the 1 to an l myself afterwards :). l is the correct id. Also, I find it odd, but $_this.attr('id') is the ONLY way this works. Others such as $(this).attr('id') and $_this.id don't do anything.

Comment: @Baez: Then there was some other issue. Maybe a typo somewhere? Doing `this.id` would be the preferred way.

Comment: this.id still doesn't work even when only changing $_this.attr('id'). I am using v1.5. Highly doubtful but maybe there's a bug.

Comment: @Baez: When you do `this.id` you're accessing the `id` property directly from the DOM element object. Accessing that property has complete browser support as a native property, so jQuery doesn't really play a role. I'd be curious to know what browser you're using.

Comment: @Baez: I'm curious about your use of `$(this).data("checked")`. Is that coming from a plugin? I tested `this.id` on an element in Opera, and it works well. Would you be willing to post a little more code in your question? If you don't have time, I understand. I'm just baffled as to what the issue would be.

Comment: @patrick dw: Sure I'd be happy to. It's too long for comments though. I can give you a link to what exactly I'm doing. Any way to PM here?

Comment: @Baez: You can either update your question, or a link would be fine too.

Comment: @patrick dw: Sorry it isn't for the public to see yet. That's why I was asking if there was a PM system :).

Comment: @Baez: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by a PM system, but I'm guessing there isn't one here. Anyway, my main concern was that you may have found a browser that had an `id` property bug. That would be a big deal. As long as `.attr()` is working for you, you might as well use that.